# How to not reveal record IDs when using them to distinguish dev elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a partial to draw plots for each record in an array of ActiveRecords.  A div's ID is used to make sure the plot is correctly drawn for the corresponding record.  My problem: I don't want to reveal the record's actual ID (vote.id) in case someone really wanted to try to scrape and correlate records.  (Maybe my client is paranoid, or maybe they have a point.)  Is there some way I can uniquely hash the IDs so they remain ambiguous?  Is there a performance hit?  (30-100 partial hits per page)

```
#Controller
@votes = Vote.where(election_id: x)

#View
<%= render partial: "voting_breakdown", collection: @votes %>

#Partial
<div id="plot_id_<%= vote.id.to_s %>"></div>
<script> jsChartLibrary.plot(data,"#plot_id_<%= vote.id.to_s %>");</script>
```

Comment: FYI: `<%= vote.id.to_s %>` never needs to include a `to_s`. the `<%= %>` already do that part for you. You've effectively written `vote.id.to_s.to_s`.

Comment: Have you tried to [base64 encode](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) your ids?

Comment: Don't want to use a simple counter in case I add async services later.

Comment: Re: base64, I would have same problem, someone would just have to decode to get record ids.